# Picasa people tags in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, picasa-web-albums

I use face tags in Picasa and Picasa allows me to choose people in my Gmail contacts.

Is there a way that I could get that person's icon in Picasa to show as that same person's icon in my contacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time it is not implemented, though it is a [highly requested feature](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=26cbb169f8f6a7c9&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, I found an acceptable workaround in the thread you linked to.